# Problem in replacing text in text area of html javascript not working

Tags: javascript

**This form is inside a while loop**
**my javascript must replace the value of spaces and newline to a value then replace it with 
 and &nbsp but its is not worling**

```
    <form method="POST" action= "edit_questions.php" onsubmit="addnewlinesdb();">
    <fieldset>
    <input type= "hidden" name="question_id" value="<?php echo $questions_id; ?>"> 
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Question" name="new_question"  value= "<?php echo $question; ?>"  autofocus>        
    <textarea id="text" class="form-control" name="answer" autofocus><?php echo strip_tags($answer); ?></textarea>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save Changes</button> 
    </form>
```

My javaScript this constains error in replacement

> ```
>     <script >
>
> function addnewlinesdb(){
>  var text1 = document.getElementById('text').value;
>       text =text1.replace(/ /g, "[sp][sp]");
>       text =text1.replace(/\n/g, "[n1]");
>   document.getElementById('text').value =text;
>
>   return false;
>
> }
> </script>
> ```

My problem the javascript is not working the replacement of its valueif(isset($_POST['submit'])){

```
$get_id =$_POST['question_id'];
$new_question = $_POST['new_question'];
$new_answer = $_POST['answer'];
$new_answer = preg_replace("#\[sp\]#", "&nbsp;",$new_answer);
$new_answer = preg_replace("#\[n1\]#", "<br>\n",$new_answer);
}
```

i have preg_replace fucntions here to filter the text and replace it but in my java script replacement of it is not working.....................................................

Comment: Do you really just want to use the `<pre>` tag? One or more white spaces, and/or new lines in HTML, create a single white space visually to the Browser User *(Client)*. What's your goal? Why is the `<form>` in a `while` loop? Please explain. In PHP I could see why you might want to do those white spaces, so the Source Code looks nice. In JavaScript, don't waste your time.

Comment: What's your error in JS? tho...`text1.replace(/\n/g, "[n1]");` should be `text.replace(/\n/g, "[n1]");`

Comment: that was a modal for editing questions and answer in my table thats why that is inside the while loop